# Relaying a HTTPS stream with Icecast2

Tags: https, audio-streaming, icecast

I am trying to relay a stream that is being broadcasted over HTTPS, is there a way to be able to do that? The documentation describes how to broadcast with https using listen-socket which I think is not what I want. All the help would be appreciated

I tried relaying normal http streams and it works. But not with https

I tried doing it both with including https and without in the url

```
`<relay>
    <server>https://streamingurl.com</server>
    <port>800</port>
    <mount>/f</mount>
    <local-mount>/f</local-mount>
    <on-demand>0</on-demand>
    <relay-shoutcast-metadata>0</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
</relay>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good workaround for this problem is to set up a reverse proxy using nginx. I did this to access a https stream over http and icecast2 is able to relay it without issues.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is currently not possible.

Answer (score 1):

What is the origin server you are trying to relay? Another Icecast or something else?

The -kh fork if Icecast supports SSL and has a lot of extensions and may be able to relay a https stream. (Sorry I'm not more help with that) see https://karlheyes.github.io

You're not supposed to include http or https in the  context, just the address.

```
    <relay>
            <server>sourceip</server>
            <port>443</port>
            <mount>/sourcemount</mount>
            <local-mount>/localmount</local-mount>
            <on-demand>0</on-demand>
            <relay-shoutcast-metadata>1</relay-shoutcast-metadata>
    </relay>
```

I just tested that with a -kh branch icecast server, and it worked, BUT I wasn't able to confirm it was actually making a SSL connection; but it is making a connection. The kh fork or Icecast will accept http or https over 80 or 443 (or any other port for that matter).

Comment: what version of icecast-kh did you test with?

Comment: I tested this with Icecast 2.4.0-kh15